# Set camera left/right

Tags: three.js

I have a `three.js` animation of a person running. I have embedded this in an iFrame on my site however the character runs off the screen. [image]

I am very happy with the positioning and the camera angle, I just need to move it right so that the character is centred in the iFrame.

Below is the code I am using.

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 4000);
camera.position.set(0, 150, 50);
camera.position.z = cz;
camera.zoom = 3.5;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
scene.add(camera);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`camera.lookAt()` method](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt), which will point the camera towards the desired position.

```js
// You could set a constant vector
var targetPos = new THREE.Vector3(50, 25, 0);
camera.lookAt(targetPos);

// You could also do it in the animation loop
// if the position will change on each frame
update() {
   person.position.x += 0.5;
   camera.lookAt(person.position);
   renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the lookAt() method wouldn't work. It will just rotate the camera, and you specified you like the camera placement/angle.

If you want to move the camera to the right along with you model, set the camera's position.x equal to model.x for every frame(assuming left/right is still the X axis).

`person.position.x += 0.5;
camera.position.x = person.position.x;`

Alternatively, you could keep the object and camera static and move the ground plane. Or even have a rotating cylinder with a big enough radius flipped on its side.